# In JSP Why Expression tag can not take the semicolon at end of statement

Tags: jsp

Expression element in the JSP
    <%=   … %>  Only one java expression
Ex:

```
 Index.jsp
 ----------
 Welcome to JSP scripting elements

  <%! int num1=10;
      int num2=20;
      int add;
   %> 

<% add=num1+num2 %>

   Addition is<%= add %> <@!-- Expression tag -->
```

Comment: Why you require semicolon ???

Comment: Because it's an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [**the Java Server Programming Black Book**](http://books.google.com/books?id=6CeZUH7wOBUC&pg=PA539&lpg=PA539&dq=%22An%20expression%20tag%20contains%20a%20scripting%20language%20expression%22&source=bl&ots=rqyZvLO2CN&sig=H2wqA_8OXSfUNK50mGWAM4RcMBw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i5L6UZH6LsmzqgGC-YCgCA&ved=0CGUQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22An%20expression%20tag%20contains%20a%20scripting%20language%20expression%22&f=false):

> **An expression tag contains a scripting language expression** that is evaluated, converted to a String, and inserted where the expression
>   appears in the JSP file. Because **the value of an expression is
>   converted to a String**, you can use an expression within text in a
>   JSP file.
>
> Like:
>
> ```
>     <%= someExpression %> 
>     <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString() %>
> ```
>
> You cannot use a semicolon to end an expression.

**In your example code**

```
<%= add %>
```

means

```
out.print(add);
```

if you have to add **semicolon** before close tag

then it is invalid

```
out.print(add;);
```

It shows some error.

[know more about JSP scripting tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaon.html)

Answer (score 4):

Because they're expressions, and not statements.

```
<%= add %>
```

is translated to

```
out.print(add);
```

So you really don't want a semicolon after the expression. It would lead to

```
out.print(add;);
```

which would not be valid Java.

Comment: This code directly goes in the _jspMethod(request, resopnse) method

Comment: @MohsinShaikh: is that a question?

Answer (score 1):

Because whatever is present after `"=" in <%= %>` that will be kept inside like `out.print(abc);`

So if you add semicolon, it will be like `out.print(abc;);` -> which is compile time error.

it is very similar to

without semicolon

```
System.out.println(abc);
```

and if you add semicolon then

```
System.out.println(abc;);
```